# How to debug Rails apps with Puma Dev and VSCode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, visual-studio-code, puma

I use [Puma dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) as my dev server. How should I setup VSCode debugger with Puma Dev remote debug?

Comment: When I was using Puma Dev I used [Pry Remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) to debug. I'm not sure how VSCode debugger works and if the two will play hand in hand (i.e. if you can use VSCode debugger from within Pry). Hopefully that either helps or steers you in some direction. You've tagged Rails here - but if you could add a little more info on your setup to the question (and where VB comes into play), that'd be dead handy :)